# Pulling out specific values from postman response and aggregating them

Tags: postman

I am getting below response in my Postman API request to pull a test execution report.

Notice that there are two set of values with "field_name": "Status". I want to aggregate these 2 values to get the following result:
Passed: 1
Unexecuted: 1

I read stuff on the internet, but could not find anything good. Appreciate the help!!

Response body JSON:

```
[
    {
        "parentId": 3171717,
        "parentType": "test-cycle",
        "automation": "No",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "test-case",
                "href": "xxxxxxx/api/v3/projects/20752/test-cases/27774385?versionId=37779716"
            },
            {
                "rel": "test-cycle",
                "href": "xxxxxxx/api/v3/projects/20752/test-cycles/3171717"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "xxxxxxx/api/v3/projects/20752/test-runs/78572177"
            }
        ],
        "id": 78572177,
        "name": "abcd test case",
        "order": 2,
        "pid": "TR-166875",
        "created_date": "2018-12-05T06:05:32-05:00",
        "last_modified_date": "2019-08-28T06:24:03-04:00",
        "properties": [
            {
                "field_id": 2522370,
                "field_name": "Run Order",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920264,
                "field_name": "Execution Type",
                "field_value": "501",
                "field_value_name": "Functional"
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920265,
                "field_name": "Planned Start Date",
                "field_value": "2016-12-23T05:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
                **"field_id": 920273,
                "field_name": "Status",
                "field_value": "605",
                "field_value_name": "Unexecuted"**
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920266,
                "field_name": "Environment",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 1055793,
                "field_name": "Build Number",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920267,
                "field_name": "Planned End Date",
                "field_value": "2016-12-23T05:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
                "field_id": 1055794,
                "field_name": "Build URL",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920269,
                "field_name": "Target Release/Build",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 1055795,
                "field_name": "CI Tool",
                "field_value": "",
                "field_value_name": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920260,
                "field_name": "Assigned To",
                "field_value": "72843",
                "field_value_name": "xxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "test_case": {
            "links": [],
            "id": 27774385
        },
        "test_case_version_id": 37779716,
        "test_case_version": "1.0",
        "creator_id": 72843
    },
    {
        "parentId": 3171717,
        "parentType": "test-cycle",
        "automation": "No",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "test-case",
                "href": "xxxxxxx/api/v3/projects/20752/test-cases/15957744?versionId=18722069"
            },
            {
                "rel": "test-cycle",
                "href": "xxxxxxx/api/v3/projects/20752/test-cycles/3171717"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "xxxxxxx/api/v3/projects/20752/test-runs/26799694"
            }
        ],
        "id": 26799694,
        "name": "xyzab",
        "order": 1,
        "pid": "TR-106714",
        "created_date": "2017-11-26T23:48:28-05:00",
        "last_modified_date": "2019-08-28T06:23:48-04:00",
        "properties": [
            {
                "field_id": 2522370,
                "field_name": "Run Order",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920264,
                "field_name": "Execution Type",
                "field_value": "501",
                "field_value_name": "Functional"
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920265,
                "field_name": "Planned Start Date",
                "field_value": "1989-12-31T05:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {   
                **"field_id": 920273,
                "field_name": "Status",
                "field_value": "601",
                "field_value_name": "Passed"**
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920266,
                "field_name": "Environment",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 1055793,
                "field_name": "Build Number",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920267,
                "field_name": "Planned End Date",
                "field_value": "2016-12-23T05:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
                "field_id": 1055794,
                "field_name": "Build URL",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920269,
                "field_name": "Target Release/Build",
                "field_value": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 1055795,
                "field_name": "CI Tool",
                "field_value": "",
                "field_value_name": ""
            },
            {
                "field_id": 920260,
                "field_name": "Assigned To",
                "field_value": "22409",
                "field_value_name": "xxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "test_case": {
            "links": [],
            "id": 15957744
        },
        "test_case_version_id": 18722069,
        "test_case_version": "1.0",
        "creator_id": 31155
    }
]
```

Comment: What stuff did you read? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DannyDainton, here's the link - https://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/

Some success in pulling data however there would be multiple instances of "status" in my response (thousands may be). So how to pull them all and get a sum of different statuses, to give execution count (passed = 600, failed = 50, unexecuted = 350 etc)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a look at some local data and this might not work for you but you could give it a go:

```
let passed = 0
let unexecuted = 0

_.each(pm.response.json(), (data) => {
    _.each(data.properties, (arrItem) => {
        if(arrItem.field_name === "Status") {
            if(arrItem.field_value_name === "Unexecuted") {
                unexectued = unexectued + 1
            }
            else if (arrItem.field_value_name === "Passed"){
                passed = passed + 1
            }

        }
    })
})

console.log(`Passed: ${passed}`)
console.log(`Unexecuted: ${unexecuted}`)
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this and I'm unsure about the performance of this code when using a larger data set but if you wanted something to work from and get a basic result in the console, this should work.